# Does changing provisioning profile affect iCloud?

Tags: ios, icloud, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

I've just added an Apple Watch to my development environment, and had to regenerate my development provisioning profile to include this device because XCode wouldn't handle it automatically. I re-ran the app on both my iPhone and iPad and now my app is showing no data even though I know there are data in iCloud. If I create data on one of the devices, this new information shows up on the other device. So, has re-creating my provisioning profile caused the devices to start ignoring the old data on iCloud, and is there any way to get back what was there?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this was nothing to do with provisioning. I had created the original data on an older version of the app. I then added an attributed to the Core Data model and implemented automatic migration which seemed to work fine, but after installing the newly provisioned version of the updated app it seemed to lose its ability to access the older data. I reinstalled the 1.0 version and the data all came back. This is troubling, as I am concerned about what will happen in the production environment if the user creates data on an older version, then installs an update. Will their data also be lost in iCloud?!

Answer (score 0):

It should migrate the data if it was replacing a similarly signed app with the same bundle ID.  If the 1.0 version came from the App Store, and you replaced it with a development or ad hoc build, it will not do the migration because of the data being stored differently for App Store builds versus non-App Store builds.  See [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1883/_index.html) for more information.

Can you confirm that both the 1.0 version and the new version were internal versions (i.e. neither came from the App Store)?

Comment: Yes these are both internal versions. The app is not yet released on the App Store. My answer above is not entirely accurate either. When I run the Watch target of my app to test the Watch extension, the existing data disappears from the phone and is replaced with data I created the first time it disappeared. Is it possible that the bundle ID of the Watch app is making the phone use a different Core Data store?

Comment: It's possible, but I find it unusual.  You're sure you didn't unintentionally change the bundle ID between version 1 and 2. If not, this could be an iOS / Xcode build bug.  I've never done iCloud CoreData with an Apple Watch extension. Have you looked at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30240585/using-same-icloud-enabled-coredata-store-across-watch-extension-and-iphone